# “Type 'Object' is not assignable to type” with new HttpClient / HttpGetModule in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried out the new `httpClient.Get` method according to the angular tutorial. But it seems for me, as it always Returns `Object`-Results.

```
// HttpClient 
getHeroes2 () {
   this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl) 
     .subscribe((data: Hero[]) => this.takeHeros2(data)); 
}

takeHeros2(heroes: Hero[]) {
  console.log(heroes)
}
```

The Parameter `heroes` in method `takeHeros2()` is of type `Object[]` and not `Hero[]`. Result of `heroes` in debugger:

[image]

I don't understand this.

Comment: Whats the output of `console.log(data)` inside `subscribe` ?

Comment: What does Hero model looks like? Please show how http is injected in service?

Comment: Add the definition of this.http and the Hero model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<Hero[]>`, you are just telling the compiler:

> Hey, when I'm calling this method, it will return an array with objects. And these objects have the same model the `Hero` class has

Where the punchline is 'objects with the same model'. Which means that they will still just be objects. If you want your objects to be of type `Hero`, try this:

```
getHeroes2() {
   this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl) 
     .map(hero => Object.assign(new Hero(), hero))
     .subscribe((data: Hero[]) => this.takeHeros2(data)); 
}
```

This uses the [`map`](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/map.html) operator from `rxjs`, which will create a `Hero` object for every object in your result array, and return it

Comment: Sounds good!
I am a C#-Boy, so I thought `get<Hero[]>` will return real _Heroes_ and not _Objects_.